# How to achieve such loading effect in asp.net web application

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, css

I want to achieve the loading effect in my asp.net web pages. I searched about it and found a [demo](http://tympanus.net/Development/CreativeLoadingEffects/) which show exactly what I want to achieve. If you see the demo, I wan to use the `YouTube` effect.

I inspected the code of this and tried to understand.
JS

```
Array.prototype.slice.call( document.querySelectorAll( '#la-buttons > button' ) ).forEach( function( el, i ) {
    var anim = el.getAttribute( 'data-anim' ),
        animEl = document.querySelector( '.' + anim );

    el.addEventListener( 'click', function() {
        if( inProgress ) return false;
        inProgress = true;
        classie.add( animEl, 'la-animate' );

        setTimeout( function() {
            classie.remove( animEl, 'la-animate' );

            inProgress = false;
        }, 6000 );
    } );
} );
```

Corresponding HTML

```
<button data-anim="la-anim-1">YouTube</button>
<button data-anim="la-anim-2">Fill from left</button>
<button data-anim="la-anim-3">Fill from down</button>
```

These are the container will shows the effect

```
<div class="la-anim-1"></div>
<div class="la-anim-2"></div>
<div class="la-anim-3"></div>
```

As you can see that in script they are using `setInterval` function to show the effect. But I want that effect should come when my asp.net web page getting loaded. So I am not sure that how to achieve it?

Please suggest so that I can achieve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i m not sure but try with this code

```
 Array.prototype.slice.call( document.querySelectorAll( '#la-buttons > button' ) ).forEach( function( el, i ) {
var anim = el.getAttribute( 'data-anim' ),
    animEl = document.querySelector( '.' + anim );

//el.addEventListener( 'click', function() {
$(document).ready(function(){
    if( inProgress ) return false;
    inProgress = true;
    classie.add( animEl, 'la-animate' );

    setTimeout( function() {
        classie.remove( animEl, 'la-animate' );

        inProgress = false;
    }, 6000 );
} );
} );
```

Comment: thanks sumit, its working. But there is an problem..in setTimeout function I have provided the `6000`. So loader always visible for 6 seconds but I want that it should be visible until my page loads. How to do that?

Comment: increase interval time to 8000 or more and then see..ready function work on load.so check it by increasing time..@sachin